# when using google directions Api and requesting data in json getting nil data

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-maps

I am new to programming and ios development with swift. I am trying to map a route between two locations and have encountered this problem.

```
func getDirections(origin: String!, destination: String!, waypoints: Array<String>!, travelMode: AnyObject!, completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if let originLocation = origin {
        if let destinationLocation = destination {
            var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation

            directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let directionsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: directionsURL!)

                println(directionsData)

                var error: NSError?
                let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
```

I am getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I tried printing the data which I was receiving and it comes out nil

```
let baseURLDirections = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directios/json?"
```

Comment: What are the `origin` and `destination` you used in your API request URL?

Comment: the 'origin' and 'destination' are the textfields in which the address are being entered in the ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt include the `API key` in your request URL.

You can use `NSURLSession` to do the Directions API request. When you get the data back from API response, you can use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()` to parse the JSON date.

```
 func directionAPITest() {

        let directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:directionURL)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request,
            completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in

                if error == nil {
                    let object = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                    println(object)

                    let routes = object["routes"] as! [NSDictionary]
                    for route in routes {
                        println(route["summary"])
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                      //update your UI here 
                    }
                }
                else {
                    println("Direction API error")
                }

        }).resume()
    }
```

If you need to udpate your `mapView` or `UITableView` you can do that inside                     the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` closure.

Comment: Thanks for this have found the error in UItextFields sending nil data to the variables

Answer (score 0):

You didnt include the `Serverkey` in your requested `URL` Not API key...Create one server key and wait for about 10 minutes to activate.