# how to implement road route navigation on google map in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps

My requirement to use **turn by turn GPS navigation**. Can anybody tell how to integrate google map for turn by turn gps navigation.

Suggest me any documentation regarding this issue. I don't want to use URL Scheme for navigation.

So please guide me how can I use map navigation in my app.

Comment: You can use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests). You can simply supply a `origin` and `destination` in your API request. Then from the API response, you can construct your polyline. You can see this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733846/when-using-google-directions-api-and-requesting-data-in-json-getting-nil-data/30740192#30740192) for how to make a sample URL request for Directions API.

Comment: I have completed this task easily with accuracy. But now my main problem is how to navigate from one position to other with driving mode.

Comment: can any one help me how can i solve my issues. I got stuck on this point .

Comment: @vikranttanwar u got any solution or not??

Comment: yes I got the solution and thanks for response

Comment: Hi, this has already been done, I am looking forward to go for "START NAVIGATION" once the route is generated. I got the route as a polyline but waiting for any suggestion to move ahead with navigation. Any solution pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Google Maps SDK then use its method to show the path between two places:

```
-(void)drawPathFrom{

    NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=true", @"Safdarjung enclave South delhi", @"chandni chownk new delhi"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"Url: %@", url);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if(!connectionError){
            NSDictionary *result        = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSArray *routes             = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];
            NSDictionary *firstRoute    = [routes objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *encodedPath       = [firstRoute[@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];

            GMSPolyline *polyPath       = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:encodedPath]];
            polyPath.strokeColor        =aNumber;
            polyPath.strokeWidth        = 5.5f;
            polyPath.map                = mapView;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Could someone write this in swift?

Answer (score 1):

For swift 4.

Although question is quite old.

```
func routingLines(origin: String,destination: String){
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving&key=\(googleapi)"


    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        let json = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
        let routes = json["routes"] as! NSArray

        for route in routes
        {
            let values = route as! NSDictionary

            let routeOverviewPolyline = values["overview_polyline"] as! NSDictionary
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline["points"] as! String
            let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points)

            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeColor = .black
            polyline.strokeWidth = 2.0
            polyline.map = self.mapView //where mapView is your @IBOutlet which is in GMSMapView!


        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let ori = "6.538729, 3.379302"
let dest = "6.444445, 3.402727"
routingLines(origin: ori,destination: dest)
```

Comment: Hi, this has already been done, I am looking forward to go for "START NAVIGATION" once the route is generated. I got the route as a polyline but waiting for any suggestion to move ahead with navigation.